# Is it possible to listen to touch events before mouse events?

Tags: .net, wpf, events, touch

I am building a WPF app,  I am working on a scenario where I need to listen for touch events before mouse events get triggered, that is when user touches the screen.

What is noticed is that mouse events always triggered before touch events.

Is there any way I can do that ? if not, is there a way I can tell if the mouse event I get is originally triggered when user touched the screen not used the mouse ?
Thanks

Comment: What touch-event are you listening to?

Try listening to PreviewTouchDown instead of TouchDown.

Can I see some code please?

Comment: I tried Preview touch events, but, its seems that mouse events always precede touch events, is there a way to prioritize touch events over mouse events ?

Comment: I can't help you with that, I'm sorry :)

Comment: its ok, I am trying to solve it at MS forums, thanks